# Why is this python web scraping code using requests package not working?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, python-requests

```
import lxml.html  
import requests  
l1=[]  
headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'}  
r = requests.get('http://www.naukri.com/jobs-by-location', headers=headers)    
html = r.content  
root = lxml.html.fromstring(html)  
urls = root.xpath('//div[4]/div/div[1]/div/a/@href') #This xpath should give the list of cities(their links)  
l1.extend(urls)
```

This python code is meant to scrape the list of job cities(their 'a href' tags) and store it in list l1. But here I am getting a blank list. The same xpath is working on Chrome console but it's not working in this code. Due to that I added headers to make my code act as a browser but still it's not working..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xx1xW.jpg

Comment: What part of your code isn't working? If you add `print l1` at the end of your code, it shows your list is populated with URLs...

Comment: Hi Drew. I don't get it. For me it's returning a blank list when I ran the code in Jupyter Qtconsole!

Comment: Well that's strange. I'm not familiar with Jupyter QtConsole though, that might have something to do with it.

Comment: It's not executing in Spyder editor either..I am using Windows 8.1 OS and have anaconda for python 2.7 installed..

Comment: Your code works fine so obviously there is something specific to how you are running the code, have you looked at the source requests returns?

Comment: Hey Padraic...What do you exactly mean by looking at source requests returns?

Comment: I mean printing `r.content`

Answer (score -1):

I tried to achieve the same using Selenium WebDriver, and this also succeeds. When this succeeds from your computer, it might be a problem in one of the used libraries.

```
import selenium.webdriver as driver

browser = driver.Chrome()
browser.get("http://www.naukri.com/jobs-by-location")
links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[4]/div/div[1]/div/a")
for link in links:
    href = link.get_attribute("href")
    print(href)
browser.quit()
```